# How to replace multiple values in a pandas dataframe?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

How can I replace multiple values with a mapping in a Pandas DataFrame?

I have one column that I want to replace with the following mapping.

```
mapping
apple=fruit
tomato=vegetable
steak=protein
milk=dairy
```

So that my column becomes.

```
col1       ->     col1
apple             fruit
apple             fruit
tomato            vegtable
steak             protein
milk              dairy
```

How can I do this most efficiently?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just create a dictionary with your mapping and then call [`Series.map`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.map.html).

```
>>> d = {'apple': 'fruit', 
         'tomato': 'vegetable', 
         'steak': 'protein', 
         'milk': 'dairy'}

>>> df.col1.map(d)

0        fruit
1        fruit
2    vegetable
3      protein
4        dairy
Name: col1, dtype: object
```

Comment: I tired using the code df[col1]=df.col1.map(d) and i got an error. A value is trying to be set on a copy of a slice from a DataFrame.
Try using .loc[row_indexer,col_indexer] = value instead

Comment: @OptimusPrime This is because of a step you must be taking before. Probably subsetting the columns of your DataFrame, doing something like `df = df[['col1', 'col2']]`. Use `df.loc` or `df.iloc` when subsetting columns instead, so that when you go to set a column like this you won't run into problems.

Comment: can you give me an example?  of using loc or iloc?  thanks